# Making a div (google map) 100% height so it fills the gap between nav bar and footer in twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and I've also implemented a sticker footer bar to the bottom of the page in a rails app. I have a two column page in the middle, basically a main page with right side bar.

Within the main page I have a canvas div I'd like to fill with a google map. This is a mapping app so I'd like to make it stretch the entire length of the space between nar bar and footer. The width 100% appears to fill the column okay, but the height doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestion? I've included the current code below:

Current bootstrap_and_override.css

```
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";

 html, body {
    height: 100%;
 }

 body { 
    padding-top: 0;
 }

 .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

 footer {
     color: #CCC;
     background: #006890;
     padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
     border-top: 1px solid #006890;
 }
 footer a {
     color: #999;
 }
 footer a:hover {
    color: #efefef;
 }
 .wrapper {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto -30px;
 }
 .push {
     height: 30px;
 }

 .logo {
     padding-top: 7px
 }

 #map_canvas { 
     height: 800px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #cccccc;
      }

 @import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

 // Set the correct sprite paths
 @iconSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png');
 @iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png');

 // Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
 // Note: If you use asset_path() here, your compiled boostrap_and_overrides.css will not 
 //       have the proper paths. So for now we use the absolute path.
 @fontAwesomeEotPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot';
 @fontAwesomeWoffPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff';
 @fontAwesomeTtfPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf';
 @fontAwesomeSvgPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.svg';

 // Font Awesome
 @import "fontawesome";

 // Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here

 @navbarBackground: #ccc;
 @navbarBackgroundHighlight: #fff;
 @navbarBrandColor: #000;
 @navbarHeight: 68px;
 @gridGutterWidth: 0px;
```

Current page content:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span9">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height: 800px;"></div>

   </div>
   <div class="span3">Right Column</div>
 </div>

 <% content_for :head do %>

 <script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
      </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function initialize() {
         var myOptions = {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.17380831799959, -94.39453125),
             zoom: 5,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
         myOptions);
   }
 </script>

 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the map to be 100%, you need to at least change this:

```
#map_canvas { 
     height: 800px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

and this:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height: 800px;"></div>
```

to height 100%.

If that doesn't help, the issues involving percentage sized map divs are discussed in this page of Mike Williams' v2 tutorial: [Part 20 Using a percentage height for the map div](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm), pretty much all the issues are the same in v3.